# Translation from Spanish "Cuenta" with "it has" or "It counts"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, translation

This is a translation question

From the Spanish:

> Cuenta con 14 campos de cultivo en los estados de Michoacán, Baja California Norte y Jalisco.

Which one would be a better translation?

> It counts with 14 cultivation fields in the states of Michoacán, Baja California Norte and Jalisco.

> It has 14 cultivation fields in the states of Michoacán, Baja California Norte and Jalisco.

Can I translate "cuenta con" with "Counts with"?

Comment: No, "counts with" is not idiomatic.   **has** is the right word choice.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, I'm not familiar with the term "idiomatic", could you explain what it means?

Comment: To be *idiomatic* a phrase must be something that a large number of native speakers would say (assuming the language has a large number of speakers). For example, in English we don't say "It does hot today" but "It *is* hot today".  "It does hot" is not idiomatic.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: Specifically, what does 'it' refer to? Please give the preceding sentence as well. Also you are getting inaccurate answers because this is not a translation forum and your translation of 'contar con' is incorrect. I suggest you go here https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=contar%20con

Answer (score 1):

I think the meaning here is closest to a [*tally*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tally), a counting of items.

> 3. *verb*
>      If you **tally** numbers, items, or totals, you count them.

In your example,

> Company X **has** 14 cultivation fields in the states of Michoacán, Baja California Norte and Jalisco.

means that someone counted the fields and the total was 14. But the statement itself does not do any counting. So I would use *has* or some other word reflecting the resulting total.

Comment: Also, it is better not to use words like "it", since we don't know what "it" refers to.